# Dynamic Jasper Report Columns

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i want to generate jasper report which is used to print on a fixed size stationary. I created html table and place all values in that as per my requirement now i want to print through java so i used jasper report now in that i have columns which is vary on time. As per my requirement i searched on internet and i got dynamic jasper is solution but in that the method add column required column name and pass variable which is from setter getter method but my whole columns are dynamic then how can i generate setter getter method or generate jasper report ?

Look Below Image

http://s1.postimg.org/ydu6pz24r/Report.jpg' border='0' alt="Report" />

Comment: You need to use a crosstab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544566/dynamic-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was created pojo of my columns and pass to detail band as a data and then after on bank pojo means which has values are empty spaces for space between columns and data. And then i send my values of columns like this tricky logic i solved my problem